# Issue with ListConvolve

Tags: functional-style, map

I am a new *Mathematica* user, learning the intricacies of functional programming. I have issues withe applying a function over a moving list. My function seems to work and give correct results but it also shows a syntax error. Can you advise how I can get rid of the syntax errors?

```
movingMap[f_, mylist_, args_, r_] := 
  ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, r], mylist, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, f &];

yalist = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10};

testfunction[x_, y_, z_, w_] := w/6*(x + 4 y + z);

movingMap[testfunction[##, 1], yalist, t, 3]
```

This gives me the correct results but also gives a syntax warning.

> {1/6 (a0 + 4 a1 + a2), 1/6 (a1 + 4 a2 + a3), 1/6 (a2 + 4 a3 + a4), 1/6 (a3 + 4 a4 + a5), 1/6 (a4 + 4 a5 + a6), 1/6 (a5 + 4 a6 + a7), 1/6 (a6 + 4 a7 + a8), 1/6 (a7 + 4 a8 + a9), 1/6 (a10 + a8 + 4 a9)}

I would appreciate advice on getting rid of the syntax error.

Comment: Move the `&` from within `movingMap` to `testfunction[##,1]&`. The simple reason: you can pass in functions using their heads alone that way, e.g. define `tf[x__] := testfunction[x]` and run `movingMap[tf, yalist,t,3]`.

Comment: Wow that was fast…

Comment: I guess I still need to get my Head about things :-)

Comment: No worries. And, puns are appreciated. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I see an empty answer area...

Comment: Out of curiosity what error message do you get?  I get none in version 7.  Presumably the message is issued for `SlotSequence` without a matching `&` but I use that form sometimes so I would like to know how later versions handle that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do not believe the OP gets an error message (I ran it on 4 different versions, just in case). But, the `##` are highlighted in pink, not green, so I think that was the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my comment answers the question, move the `&` from within `movingMap` to `testfunction[##,1]&`, as follows:

```
movingMap[f_, mylist_, args_, r_] := 
  ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, r], mylist, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, f];

movingMap[testfunction[##, 1]&, yalist, t, 3]
```

The simple reason: you can pass in functions using their heads alone that way, e.g. define

```
tf[x__] := testfunction[x]
```

and run

```
movingMap[tf, yalist, t, 3]
```